# Pytorch Indexing

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor [[1,2],[4,5],[7,8]] and a tensor with indices [0,1,0].

I want to apply them to second dimension so that it returns: [1,5,8].

How should I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that it should return `[1, 5, 7]`? Also, how did you try to index your tensor and what was the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import torch

arr=torch.tensor([[1,2],[4,5],[7,8]])
indices_arr=torch.tensor([0,1,0])

ret=arr[[0,1,2],indices_arr]
# print(ret)
# tensor([1, 5, 7])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean [1, 5, 7] for the output:

One solution would be to combine a tensor of all indices for dimension 0 and the desired indices for dimension 1.

```
tensor = torch.tensor([[1,2],[4,5],[7,8]])
indices = torch.tensor([0,1,0])
output = tensor[torch.arange(0, tensor.size[0]), indices]
```

output:

```
tensor([1, 5, 7])
```